# Metasearch Live Search

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Tring to modify the basic [railscasts Search, AJAX](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) with metasearch.

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Customer.search(params[:search])
    @customers = @search.all)
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for @search, :html => {:method => :get}, :id => "customers_search", :remote => true do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :firstname_or_lastname_contains %>
        <%= f.text_field :firstname_or_lastname_contains %><br />
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>

    <div id="customers"> <%= render 'customers' %> ... all the customer basic layout
    </div>

    <p><%= link_to "New Customer", new_customer_url %></p>
```

index.js.erb

```
$("#customers").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("customers")) %>");
```

application.js

```
$(function() {
  $("#customers_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#customers_search").attr("action"), $("#customers_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: To quote Alex Trebek, "that must be in the form of a question." How is your solution working out so far? Are you having a specific problem you need help with? Any console output that might help? Just posting "I'm tring [sic] to do X" with a bunch of code doesn't give us much to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain if you were able to get this to work, but I was able to do so by realizing that the search form is named by default by meta_search to for example "#customer_search", so remove the :id => from form_for

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @search, :remote => true do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :firstname_or_lastname_contains %>
        <%= f.text_field :firstname_or_lastname_contains %><br />
        <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**application.js**

```
$(function() {
  $("#customer_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#customer_search").attr("action"), $("#customer_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

I haven't yet figured out how to get the document title to render in a readable way from episode 246
**index.js.erb**

```
$("#customers").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("customers")) %>");
document.title = "<%= escape_javascript("#{params[:search].to_s.titleize} - Page #{params[:page] || 1}") %>";
```

as this prints

```
{&quot;Station Name Or Address Contains&quot;=&gt;&quot;As&quot;} - Page 1
```

to the title bar and history

Comment: BTW - for fix the title just add .html_safe to the end of doc title. document.title = "<%= escape_javascript("#{params[:search].to_s.titleize} - Page #{params[:page] || 1}").html_safe %>";